# Create date_from and date_to columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a table named 'T1' which I want to transpose and have date_from and date_to columns. The table itself has the data of who is a manager of a particular company. So I want to know since when to when a user was responsible for a company. I can do it easily in BigQuery with the following query but I'm struggling to do the same in MySQL.

```
WITH T1 AS (  SELECT  9 as rating, 'company1' as cid, 100 as user, '2017-08-20' AS created UNION ALL
          SELECT  9 as rating, 'company1' as cid, 101 as user, '2017-08-22' AS created UNION ALL
          SELECT 10 as rating, 'company1' as cid, 101 as user, '2017-08-21' AS created

        )

    SELECT cid, rating, user, CAST(created as DATE) as date_from,
          CAST(COALESCE(MIN(CAST(created as DATE)) OVER(PARTITION BY cid, rating ORDER BY CAST(created as DATE) DESC ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),
          DATE_ADD(current_date(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) as DATE) AS date_to
         FROM T1
```

The original table format:

```
rating  cid user    created  
9   company1    100 2017-08-20   
9   company1    101 2017-08-22   
10  company1    101 2017-08-21
```

The final table should have the following format:

```
cid rating  user    date_from   date_to  
1   company1    9   101 2017-08-22  2018-02-24   
2   company1    9   100 2017-08-20  2017-08-22   
3   company1    10  101 2017-08-21  2018-02-24
```

Thank you!

Comment: It is not really clear what you want to accomplish. Is a manager of a company manager until someone else is the manager of the company?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need `lead()`, which is not available in MySQL (and which would make the BigQuery query simpler).  One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.*, t1.created as date_from,
       (select min(tt1.created)
        from t1 tt1
        where tt1.cid = t1.cid and tt1.created > t1.created
       ) as date_to
from t1;
```

Comment: Great! Awesome :)